# React function passed to child through props is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

I am trying to pass `selectNotebook` to `notebookNav` to be used in an `onClick()` function.  I can see `selectNotebook` in my prop in React dev tools, but whenever I click a button, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectNotebook' of undefined(…)`.

This is my parent component:

```
var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      notebooks: this.props.notebooks,
      nav: this.props.nav
    };
  },

  selectNotebook: function(id) {
    const nav = {...this.state.nav};
    nav[notebook] = this.props.notebooks[id];
    this.setState({nav})
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={{"height": "100%"}}>
        <NotebookNav 
          notebooks={this.props.notebooks}
          selectNotebook={this.selectNotebook}
        >
        </NotebookNav>
        <Technique></Technique>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This is the child component:

```
var NotebookNav = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    notebooks = this.props.notebooks;

    return (
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="panel panel-info">
          <div className="panel-heading">
            <h4 className="panel-title">Your Notebooks</h4>
          </div>

          <div className="panel-body">
            <ul className="breadcrumb" 
              style={{"backgroundColor": "#fff", "marginBottom": "0"}}
            >
              <li className="active">
                notebooks
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <div className="btn-group-vertical" style={{"width": "100%"}}>
                {notebooks.map( function (notebook) {
                  return(
                    <li 
                      key={notebook.id} 
                      className="btn btn-block btn-raised btn-lg"
                      onClick={() => this.props.selectNotebook(notebook.id)}
                    >
                      {notebook.name}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      <div className="btn-group-vertical" style={{"width": "100%"}}>
        {notebooks.map( function (notebook) {
          return(
            <li 
              key={notebook.id} 
              className="btn btn-block btn-raised btn-lg"
              onClick={() => this.props.selectNotebook(notebook.id)}
            >
              {notebook.name}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

The problem is that transform function passed to `map` will create it's own scope, where `this` is undefined. To fix this, [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a second argument for the scope where you can pass `this` from your outer scope:

```
{notebooks.map(function (notebook) { ... }, this)
```

If you target environment supports it you can also use an arrow function, which implicitly uses the outer scope:

```
{notebooks.map((notebook) => { ... })}
```

Answer (score 1):

try passing it by binding using this:-

```
<NotebookNav 
      notebooks={this.props.notebooks}
      selectNotebook={this.selectNotebook.bind(this)}
    >
```

and then on your child element as well use arrow function so that its bound:-

```
{notebooks.map( (notebook) => {
      return(
        <li 
          key={notebook.id} 
          className="btn btn-block btn-raised btn-lg"
          onClick={() => this.props.selectNotebook(notebook.id)}
        >
          {notebook.name}
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when using `createClass` instead of the es6 `extends React.component`, `this` is bound automatically.  If you bid as you suggest while using `createClass` it will throw an error at you.